# How to best handle property set as `SomeType[] | unknown`?

Tags: typescript

I receive some data through an API call, one of these properties is set to `SomeType[] | unknown`, think of it as my data looking something like this:

```js
interface SomeType {
  name: string
  enabled: boolean
}

interface MyData {
  id: string
  name: string
  someArrayProperties: SomeType[] | unknown
}
```

I have a lot of array methods iterating over `someArrayProperties`, so multiple instances of stuff like this:

```js
const enabledProperty = myData.someArrayProperties.find((property: SomeType) => property.enabled)
```

I would think this should be nice an easy to resolve, but I am constantly getting errors related to the `unknown` type that is also set on `someArrayProperties`

> Argument of type '(property: SomeType) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, obj: unknown[]) => unknown'.
> Translation: I was expecting (value: unknown, index: number, obj: unknown[]) => unknown, but you passed (property: SomeType) => boolean

A way to resolve this would be to always to set `(property as SomeType).enabled`:

```js
const enabledProperty = myData.someArrayProperties.find((property) => (property as SomeType).enabled)
```

or alternatively set `(myData.someArrayProperties as SomeType[]).find`:

```js
const enabledProperty = (myData.someArrayProperties as SomeType[]).find((property) => property.enabled)
```

but this feels like a cop-out and not appropriately addressing the problem, not to mention that it would have to be done quite a lot.

Anyway, even though this does technically fix the TS errors I am getting, I'd like to know of a better way to deal with it if there is one.

Thanks!

Comment: something typed `SomeType[] | unknown` collapses to just `unknown`. You will see this when hovering over the property. So `SomeType[]` really has no effect here.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I don't think I have control over this data :( So is there anyway it could be remedied on my end as just a consumer of it?

Comment: when you get the data, you should first check if the type of `someArrayProperties` really is `SomeType[]`. If yes, assign the data the correct type where `someArrayProperties` has the type `SomeType[]` and you can now use these methods safely. If not, give it the type `unknown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isSomeTypeArray(obj: MyData): obj is MyData & { someArrayProperties: SomeType[] } {
  return Array.isArray(obj.someArrayProperties) 
    && obj.someArrayProperties.every(
      (e) => typeof e.name === "string" && typeof e.enabled === "boolean"
    )
}
```

The type guard checks the shape of an object to determine if the `someArrayProperties` field really contains an array of type `SomeType`.

```
async function main(){
  const data = await fetch("abc.com").then((data) => data.json()) as MyData

  if (isSomeTypeArray(data)){
    const enabledProperty = data.someArrayProperties.find((property) => property.enabled)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8AoZZEObALmQGcwpQBzc5CKgIwBsIATOl3To%20cEKQC%20pUqEixEKALJ4AInDBxkZCsEEMmrdlVoHmINhXpYIAQShQ4eAApR0RKGGAR6dAK4gANYg6ADuEtIyMAEIXuggyMD0GNj4RPaOeAAU6FwAVnQq6poAlHS5eYn0yEUaWgBk2gw2GU6u7tBePnQpuIQQANoAusiS2uxQEGB%20UAmteAB0SfM5%20QvW2PPtHl30JcjsFPWNFestDm1uO970CxAAbtDZhxTIWRD7ALwAfMhg-egYBwFiYUJ9wcgAESMcwsSHIY5-AFAiB3bh8fjIcGfKHCUQQcSQl4lKQyOD0PAgBDIaJUuIJTBwUBZEo6ZAIeKMZD8OpY5BwUJMsA0qYIAAWWUhcC4CAWHMwkJKCzAYs4WSyPNKWN%20mrgCzy1hALP25JqajqMl0QKySV6aTsF2yupKrJeHJAXM40ox206eD5urOm0dvs8NwWMFA-HVBCufq%20v1jHU8iy9vAEJIo0kkQA)